# trait good practice to save Scala constants?

Tags: scala

Is a trait a good way to put together all the constants that will be used by certain classes?
Or is there maybe a better way to handle constants, like a package object?

Comment: Class constants are best placed in the companion object with the "static" methods. More general constants go in a separate object that can be imported if necessary. Avoid package objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton objects can contain fields, like any other object. If a constant exists on its own, it makes sense to put it in a singleton. Don't make a singleton *just* for all constants, but if they're logically grouped together, then you could pretty easily make an `object` with a good name.

```
object Calendar {
  val DaysInYear = 365
  val DaysInWeek = 7
  val EpochYear = 1970
  // ... etc ...
}
```

Package objects are [deprecated](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/package-objects.html) in Scala 3 and set to be removed in the future. If you're already using Scala 3, then you can just put individual constants at the top-level of a file. Otherwise, throwing them in a singleton is the most future-proof way to code right now.